# How to switch out .csv files in d3.js with a button?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, state, concatenation

I have a series of .csv files (file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv etc.) that need to be switched out on the click of a button.  My thought was to add 1 to a variable every time it is clicked and concatenate the number to the file name.  What I have is listed below, where in the first script I am creating the functionality of the button and in the second script I am using d3.js in order to read the csv files.  Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

```
<script> 
    var ptOne = "films";
    var ptTwo = 1;
    var ptThree = ".csv"
    var fileName = ptOne.concat(ptTwo).concat(ptThree);


    button.on("click", function() {
         ptTwo+1;
    })
</script>
<script>



  d3.csv(fileName, function(data) { 
      var w = 1000;
      var h = 500;
      var padding = 100;
```

Comment: Do note that unless you have infinitely many files, you'll eventually load a non-existent one. Might be easier to loop over an array of pre-defined names. Keep a counter, then just select out the next array element.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. How does your current solution not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function to read the csv file like:

```
function readCsv(fileName) {
    d3.csv(fileName, function(data) { 
        var w = 1000;
        var h = 500;
        var padding = 100;
        ...
    }
}
```

And then call the function on click:

```
button.on("click", function() {
    ptTwo+1;
    readCsv(ptOne+ptTwo+ptThree)
})
```

Finally I would initialize the page with the first csv file:

```
readCsv(ptOne+1+ptThree)
```

I hope it helps.